# Q: Unexpected behavior from digital Rheostat

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, rheostat

I have no idea whats warranting this behavior from the [MCP4162](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/22059b.pdf) device

Starting from 500mV(pp) - 2.8V(pp) a weird "wave" like distortion happens in between the two voltages. (Towards the negative cycle).

This only happens at low frequencies such as 20Hz and lower, however at higher frequencies this no longer occurs even with the voltage range described above.

Input 1 = Input (Yellow)

Input 2 = Output (Green)

The behavior:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Diagram

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f77zV5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Never used them, but watch out for ": Non-linearity is affected by wiper resistance (RW), which changes significantly over voltage and
temperature." and considering the long time constant from C2 , watch out for excessive xxx uA current related distortion during startup.

Comment: I see I see, but does it make sense to only be distorted between those voltages? I was thinking of scrapping this and trying out this guy http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/11195c.pdf

Comment: These digipots use FETS. As you apply LARGE voltages, the FETs experience major channel-gate voltage changes, and the on-resistance will change a lot, which changes your resistance and changes your gain. Is this effect discussed in the datasheet?

Comment: Thats interesting, I thought they would use latches/relays. I have no idea. I am not experience what so ever in these type of applications. I tried looking for anything but I couldnt find anything related to what to avoid, etc. Why is that when I apply a large voltage is good, and a small voltage, but in between its not good? Does that explain its behavior ?

Comment: Neither end of the digital pot should ever exceed the supply voltage **of the digital pot**. You don't show the supply voltage for the digital pot. Measure the voltage at both side of the pot when you see the distortion (one side on each channel), **using DC coupling on both channels**.

Comment: Sorry, the reason I didnt include it is just to keep the diagram organized. The supply voltage for the Rheostat is 5V.

Comment: Before you apply any input voltage the output is already at the digital pot supply voltage nominally.

Comment: Sorry I dont understand you, but let me check the voltage on the pot for you

Comment: VDD =5 and vss = 0

Comment: I believe it has to do with the ardunio sampling at low frequencies? The Rheostat is being connect to an ardunio, perhaps? thats it?